# get diff between date times in php

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I was previously using the php strtotime function to calculate the diff between two timestamps to check the duration of a given appointment. Now I need to include the dates as well as times as certain appointments can go for more than one day.

**Previous code:**

```
$duration = date('H:i',strtotime($row['scheduleTimeEnd']) - strtotime($row['scheduleTime']) - 3600)
```

**New attempt with dates:**

```
$duration = date('H:i',strtotime($row['scheduleDateEnd'].'T'.$row['scheduleTimeEnd']) 
- strtotime($row['scheduleDate'].'T'.$row['scheduleTime']) - 3600)
```

Both pieces of code produce the same results. i.e. I have an appointment in my JSON feed which goes from 12th May 10:20 to the 18th May 17:20 and the duration values being returned by oth pieces of code below is 07:09.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php and http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: I think the frmat is the problem `d H:i` instead of `H:i` you don't?

Comment: @Maraboc thank you that was it! Is there a way to only display the day if it goes on for more than 24 hrs? i.e. most duration values will now look something like this: 01 xx:xx.

Comment: @user2363025 i added an answer to help other poeple facing the same problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the time difference -

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2015-05-17 17:20:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('2015-05-12 10:00:00');

$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
$days = $interval->days;
$hours = ($days * 24) + $interval->h;
echo "Difference : ". $hours .' : '.$interval->i;
```

Use DateTime Interface.

**Output**

```
Difference : 127 : 20
```

Comment: You need to use the Datetime interface to create date object.

Comment: I realised I left that bit out. Works now, thanks and accepted

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the format of the `date` method you should updated like that :

```
$duration = date('d H:i' ,strtotime(
                   $row['scheduleDateEnd'].'T'.$row['scheduleTimeEnd']) 
                 - strtotime($row['scheduleDate'].'T'.$row['scheduleTime']) - 3600)
```

By the format i mean `d H:i` ^^. ==> [Doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php)